# Recyclerview sqllite update only works on first item on the list

Tags: java, android

I have a list of items that are displayed in a recylcerview in my adapter class i implmented a onlongclick method, when used it opens up a new alertdialog, when i press on the selected item in the alterdialog im calling `updateList()` function that is supposed to update the selected item the problem is this only works for the first item displayed in my list, so in exmaple if i pressed the 10th item on the list said item wont update.

**Update function**

```
public boolean updateList(long rowId, String stanje) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(TABELA_STOLPEC_STANJE,stanje);
    return db.update(TABELA_IME,newValues,TABELA_STOLPEC_ID+"="+rowId,null)>0;

}
```

**OnlongClickListener** this method is in my fragment class.

```
mmAdapter.setOnLongClick(new ToDoRecyclerViewAdapter.OnLongClickListener_() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(long i,String item) {
                if(item.equals("doing")) {
                    boolean update_1 = db.updateList(i, item);
                    if(update_1) {                        
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.detach(TodoFragment.this).attach(TodoFragment.this).commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dodano v bazo.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Prislo je do napake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

**onlongclicklistener implementation** in my adapter class

```
holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            CharSequence meni[] = new CharSequence[] {"DOING"};
            adb.setItems(meni, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    mValues.get(i).setStanje("doing");
                    clickLinster_.onLongClick(mValues.get(position).getId_(),mValues.get(position).getStanje());
                }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

   public interface OnLongClickListener_ {
    void onLongClick(long i, String item);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple, you are updating wrong row with index, correct solution:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Rest of onBindViewHolder code

    holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
            final int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            CharSequence meni[] = new CharSequence[] {"DOING"};
            adb.setItems(meni, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    mValues.get(pos).setStanje("doing");
                    clickLinster_.onLongClick(mValues.get(pos).getId_(),mValues.get(pos).getStanje());
                }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Sadly it didnt fix my issue, same as before.

Comment: Nevermind a mistake on my part, it works perfectly, thank you!